# JSoup | Fetching part of the HTML

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I have problem with fetch site with car ads. I would like to get advertiser's name from it. The main problem is that sometimes that name is showing in different way.

1) Name is **Kajetan**

(https://www.otomoto.pl/oferta/mercedes-benz-klasa-e-w211-bardzo-dobry-stan-bez-wkladu-finansowego-warszawa-ryki-ID6BEBy9.html#2bd424144f)

```
   <div class="seller-box__seller-info">
    <small class="seller-box__seller-registration">Sprzedający na OTOMOTO od 2015</small>
    <small class="seller-box__seller-type">Osoba prywatna</small>
    <h2 class="seller-box__seller-name"> Kajetan </h2>
   </div>
```

2) Name is **AS MOTORS Centrum Pojazdów Używanych KIA**

(https://www.otomoto.pl/oferta/kia-ceed-1-6-crdi-136-km-m-bws-fvat-salon-serwis-polska-ID6BHFu3.html#2bd424144f)

```
<div class="seller-box__seller-info">
 <small class="seller-box__seller-registration">Sprzedający na OTOMOTO od 2019</small>
 <small class="seller-box__seller-type">Dealer</small>
   <h2 class="seller-box__seller-name">
   <div class="seller-badge"> <img src="xx.jpg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Ten dealer korzysta z pakietu usług Premium Plus" class="">
   </div>
    <a href="https://asmotorsuzywane.otomoto.pl" title="AS MOTORS Centrum Pojazdów Używanych KIA">AS MOTORS Centrum Pojazdów Używanych KIA</a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

In the first case the solution is easy because I'll do it like this:

```
public static String fetchOwnerName (String html) {
        Elements ownerElement = Jsoup.parse(html).getElementsByClass("seller-box__seller-info").select("h2");
        String owner = StringUtils.substringBetween(String.valueOf(ownerElement), "\">", "</h2>");
        return owner;
    }
```

But in the second case the problem is that after `<h2>` there are additional `<div>` and what is more, name of the advertiser is between `<a href=""`.

How should I change fetchOwnerName method to be universal? I'm using JSOUP library to parse HTML page. Thanks for all of your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get text inside the h2 tags without worrying about the additional tags `i.e` `div` `a`

You just have to call `.text()`

```
Elements ownerElement = Jsoup.parse(html).getElementsByClass("seller-box__seller-info").select("h2");
String owner = ownerElement.text();
```

This will work if no other text except advertiser's name is present between `h2` tags